# class object as vector element , destructor getting called too many times

Tags: c++, destructor

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class A
{
    static int k;
    public:
    A(){k++ ; cout << "constructor : " <<k<< endl;};
    ~A(){k--; cout << "destructor : "  << k <<endl;};
    void show() { cout<<"current value of k = "<<k<<endl; }
};
int A::k = 0;
int main( )
{
    vector<A> test;
    test.push_back(A());
    test.emplace(test.end(), A()); 
    test[0].show();
    cout<<test.size()<<endl;
    return 0; 
}
```

Output:

> constructor : 1
>
> destructor : 0
>
> constructor : 1
>
> destructor : 0
>
> destructor : -1
>
> current value of k = -1
>
> 2
>
> destructor : -2
>
> destructor : -3

Why has the destructor been called too many times, as it should have been called just twice since the constructor only gets called twice? How to avoid this situation?

Comment: When you call `emplace` you are suppose to supply the arguments to the class constructor, not an instance of the class.

Comment: @Sean Nothing wrong with that. That instance will be passed to the copy constructor. It might be slightly inefficient compared to the alternative but not a bug.

Answer (score 4):

You're making copies, but your trace output doesn't show that (and your `k` doesn't get incremented when it happens). So the "extra" destructor calls go with copy constructions.

You can remove one of the copies by using `emplace` properly:

```
test.emplace(test.end());
//                     ^ no A() here; that would be like doing test.push_back(A(A()))
```

but you still have a copy in the `push_back` itself.

Write a copy constructor so that your trace output accounts for those operations:

```
A(const A&) { k++; cout << "copy-constructor : " << k << endl; }
```

(I wouldn't bother with a move constructor, as [that'll `delete` the copy assignment operator and all hell will break loose](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c4724d4d45c8331e).)

---

Finished code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class A
{
    static int k;

public:
    A()         { k++; cout << "constructor : "      << k << endl; }
    ~A()        { k--; cout << "destructor : "       << k << endl; }
    A(const A&) { k++; cout << "copy-constructor : " << k << endl; }

    void show() { cout << "current value of k = " << k << endl; }
};

int A::k = 0;

int main()
{
    vector<A> test;

    test.push_back(A());
    test.emplace(test.end(), A());

    test[0].show();
    cout << test.size() << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
constructor : 1
copy-constructor : 2
destructor : 1
constructor : 2
copy-constructor : 3
copy-constructor : 4
destructor : 3
destructor : 2
current value of k = 2
2
destructor : 1
destructor : 0
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a225b5ed2c138ea5))

Answer (score 4):

A compiler-generated copy constructor is being used, which doesn't increment `k`.

Include that explicitly in your source code, and all will be well.